# Update select "the Angular Way"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to manipulate a `<select>` tag so that it has a different text colour depending on whether the default, disabled `<option>` is selected or a valid option.

My guess was to put an `ng-change` directive and pass it an update function, but I don't know what flags I can pass to my function... [The documentation is pretty useless to me.](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)

Here is my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/33QFj/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, don't mess with DOM changes and manipulations anywhere except in a directive.
Hence, you have 2 options:
1) Create a directive to do DOM manipulations to your select.
2) Use ng-class to change the class according to some logic.
Here's your example with using the ng-class:
http://jsfiddle.net/WkFR8/
I changed your  code a bit:

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <select ng-model="val" ng-options="opt.name for opt in options" ng-class="{two: val}">
        <option disabled value="">Default</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Note the ng-class I've added. I'm assuming you wanted the text to be blue if we choose anything in the drop down except default.
What the ng-class did was to check if val has something in it (e.g. not 0, not null, not "" etc.) and this rule is satisfied when we change the select value. In this case, the class "two" is added to the element.

Comment: Perfect!! Can we go into chat so I can ask you some more questions?

Comment: How do we go into chat?

Comment: Go to chat.stackoverflow.com I think, and then I can initiate a conversation with you

Answer (score 1):

I think `ng-class` is what you are looking for.

Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/rBQu9/1/

Comment: Shows a little more functionality in here that I haven't seen before, but your answer was second

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, I discovered another possible solution particular to this problem.

Since Angular will set classes to the form [as defined here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController), I can use these classes for styling.

So, when a user selects anything other than the disabled default, I know that I can look for the `ng-dirty` class and style it like that.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/33QFj/3/

Comment: That is probably a better approach for forms. `ng-class` is useful many other places though. Take for example comparing two number values then showing an indicator red or green based on up or down trends. You can do expressions in `ng-class` as well.